# How to use reduce/map/list comprehension for a summation?

Tags: python, sum, generator-expression

[image]
I have a equation above, and I want to calculate the summation underlined in red, and [ρ0,ρ1,ρ2,...,ρN] is a list to begin with.

A for loop can surely solve the problem. But I was wondering if there is a more concise pythonic style for it. 
I tried reduce function, but it seems like it only works on direct summation or multiplication of a list. What is the way to work on the summation like the one shown above?

Comment: Thank you for the answers! I solved the first term, and I slightly changed the question. Now I am working on the second term. It is a little bit harder...

Comment: What are these terms called?

Comment: @zleung Don't change the question like that.  It makes it look like people are answering the wrong question.  Keep the previous question as is, accept the answer that was most useful to you and ask a new question for your new problem.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
sum((x-y)**2 for (x,y) in izip(a, a[1:]))
```

for an array `a`.
The `izip(a, a[1:])` allows you access to the i'th and i+1'th elements of the array at the same time.

Comment: I'd reccomend using izip instead of zip. Get's you a little extra speed for large datasets.

Comment: @Daniel If they are on python3, then `zip` *is* `izip`.

Comment: @SethMMorton That's true. Just wanted to point it out since it's not mentioned here which version is being used.

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be better to use `numpy` for this, but in pure python, you can sum a generator expression. e.g.

```
>>> sum(i**2 for i in range(10))
285
```

For your second term, just nest summations:

```
>>> sum(sum(i*j for i in range(10)) for j in range(10))
2025
```

where my `i*j` term is your function for calculating the product of your rho differences and cosine term.

Comment: Those terms are used to calculate the X-ray reflectivity fora  given electron density profile.

Comment: Thank you for your help. For the first term I prefer @GuyGreer 's answer, whereas your answer works better for double summation. Numpy does not seem to support i**2 or i*j kind of stuff as its arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can try to write a recursive function

```
def listsum(numList):
   if len(numList) == 2:
        return math.pow(numList[0] - numList[1], 2)
   else:
        return math.pow(numList[0] - numList[1], 2) + listsum(numList[1:])
```

And call it

```
listsum([1,3,5,7,9])
```